# How to get a custom attribute for an object instance from inside the class

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I created a custom attribute `CustomAtt` that I'm using in a field from a class `Test`:

```
public class Test
{
    [CustomAtt("test")]
    private MyOtherClass obj;
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve the value from the custom attribute not inside the class `Test`but in `MyOtherClass` like:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    MyOtherClass ()
    {
        //how do I get here the value ("test") from the custom attribute
        //CustomAtt for this class instance?
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `typeof(Test).GetCustomAttributes<CustomAtt>()`.

Comment: Note that the question talks about private field decorated with the attribute, not the type `Test` itself. Code in MyOtherClass could get Test's private field decorations via reflection.

Comment: Yes, right, sorry. I was just trying to point OP into using `typeof()`, but did not consider this deserving a full answer. There should be `GetField(...)` between (cannot edit original comment now).

Comment: Yes, this way would work, but I want a generic way. Pay attention that I can have this custom attribute in any field of any class. So I want to get via reflection the attribute from within the ``MyOtherClass``. I was expecting something like ``GetType().GetInstanceField().GetCustomAttribute``. Maybe it's utopic, but that's why I posted here ;)